# Degrees of freedom of a symmetric orthogonal 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Playing computationaly with the constraints implied by the orthogonality condition $A^T A=I$ on the elements of the symmetric matrix $A$, I found out that the number of degrees of freedom in it is 2.

Obviously, being $O(3)$ a group of dimension 3, a general orthogonal matrix has 3 degrees of freedom, but I can't easily grasp on why/how the simmetry condition eliminates one of them (evidently it would eliminate at least one, but I'm looking for a formal understanding of this).

So, the question: What is the formalism and how to show that the number of degrees of freedom of a symmetric orthogonal 3x3 matrix is 2 (if i'm not mistaken)?

It would be really helpful if the answer could be detailed or contain friendly references (I need to understand this to justify an ansatz in a physics paper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix corresponds to a choice of three unit vectors (the columns of the matrix) that are all mutually orthogonal. The first vector can be freely chosen on the unit sphere (two degrees of freedom), and once that's chosen, the second vector may be chosen freely on the "equator" (using the first vector as the "north pole"), which has one degree of freedom. Finally, the last vector you only have two available options, so that doesn't contribute a degree of freedom.

If we decide the determinant *first*, then the third vector has no choice associated with it at all. This way we can see the space of points on $\Bbb R^9$ that corresponds to orthogonal matrices as two $3$-dimensional subspaces, one for each choice of determinant.

If we also want the matrix to be symmetric, then we can think in a similar way, but trying to adapt the *exact* same visualisation will be tricky: first you pick a vector on the unit sphere, and then you pick a second vector on the corresponding equator knowing what the $x$-coordinate already is, and then the third vector micht not even be possible to choose. So no, this doesn't quite work.

A symmetric matrix is diagonalisable. Which is to say, it has three real eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct, but counted with geometric multiplicity). The orthogonality means it's an isometry, so the only valid eigenvalues are $1$ and $-11$. Now we can split into cases depending on the signature (combination of $+1$ and $-1$ for eigenvalues), and look at what freedom we have to choose the eigenvectors / eigenspaces. This is similar to how we in the orthogonal case could decide the determinant first.

1. $\{1, 1, 1\}$: Then the matrix is necessarily the identity matrix, so no degrees of freedom.
2. $\{1, 1, -1\}$: Then we may pick the (one-dimensional) eigenspace corresponding to the $-1$ eigenvalue freely, which gives us two degrees of freedom. The eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ will necessarily be 2-dimensional and orthogonal to the $-1$ eigenspace, so no choice left.
3. $\{1, -1, -1\}$: Very similar to point 2. Two degrees of freedom.
4. $\{-1, -1, -1\}$: Very similar to point 1. No degrees of freedom.

So we end up with first a choice of signature (from four options), two of the options give no degrees of freedom, while two of the options give two degrees of freedom. So the space of orthogonal, symmetric matrices has two degrees of freedom. The corresponding subspace of $\Bbb R^9$ consists of two points as well as two two-dimensional surfaces (each homeomorphic to the real projective plane).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! One question: where does the symmetry enters the argument? It guarantees that the matrix is diagonalizable over the reals but don't think I'm grasping exactly how this factors in in the counting of the number of degrees of freedom.

Comment: @GaloisFan Symmetry grants so-called orthogonal diagonalisation. In other words, it means we can find three pairwise orthogonal eigenvectors. However, to describe the linear transformation, all we really need is the _eigenspaces_, not the eigenvectors. So either there is one 3-dimensional eigenspace, or there is one 2-dimensional and one 1-dimensional, or there are three 1-dimensional eigenspaces. Then orthogonality comes in and limits the possible eigenvalues (and in the process makes the "three 1-dimensional eigenspaces" option impossible).

Comment: Right. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I realized that this is still not clear to me. How can I see that studying the d.o.f. of the eigenspaces is enough to understand the d.o.f. of the matrix itself? How would this work in the purely symmetric case (I suppose that each eigenspace would contribute with 2 d.o.f.: 3x2=6)? And in our case, of one one-dimensional eigenspace and two-dimensional ones: ok, we choose the 1D space vector arbitrarily fixing two of the d.o.f. Then the other subspace is necessarily orthogonal, but we could rotate the vector pair simultaneously freely 'in the equator'.

Comment: @GaloisFan But we're not choosing three eigenvectors. We're choosing two eigenspaces. That has fewer degrees of freedom. And once you have the eigenspaces, how the linear map works on any vector (and thus what all the entries are) is fixed.